# Workaround for unsupported keyboard

Tags: pi-3, keyboard, input-device

I have couple keyboards now sitting in the desk but somehow it refuse to work on raspi3 Jessie with pixel (genius kb100-holtek semiconductor and prolink usb keyboard) , both tried using powered usb hub and without it. From the list in [this elinux](http://linux.org/RPi_USB_Keyboards) website. Instead buying a supported keyboard, can i just install the driver or other stuff to make it work?

Comment: There is no such thing as "raspi3 wheezy". Raspberry Pi3 requires the latest firmware, and there was never a Wheezy version.

Comment: Thanks @milliways for pointing that out, i mean raspbian jessie

Comment: Keyboards are cheap.  Nice small wired ones and good wireless Logitech ones are all available on the Walmart website.

Comment: so, basically it cannot be done?